# Enable context-sensitive help in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Using Eclipse Mars (4.5) to write a Java application. Say I'm trying to see the documentation for the keyword `final`. I put the cursor in the middle of "final" in the line `final static int RIGHT_PADDING = 12;` and hit <kbd>F1</kbd>.

In `Delphi` and `Visual Studio` a related keyword might be `const` and the context help displays correctly. In Eclipse, I would expect the relevant Java documentation to be displayed in Eclipse or possibly in a web browser (either is fine). The relevant page might be [this Oracle Java documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#FINAL).

Instead I get this `Help` panel which appears on the right as in the image below. No help on `final` is displayed. I've tried setting some of the `Windows > Preferences > General > Keys` binding for `help`-related commands to <kbd>F1</kbd> but so far without success.

[image: Eclipse Help panel]

- Is this functionality available in Eclipse Mars?
- Do I need to use a different key binding other than <kbd>F1</kbd>?

Comment: Is it really about `java` programming language?

Comment: Possibly not directly, though I expect the answer to be relevant since I may need to configure something to link to the Oracle documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse Java editor supports context-sensitive help only for names (of classes,
methods, fields, variables), but not  for keywords (like `final`, `class`, `int`).
AFAIK the same holds for other language editors (C/C++, JavaScript, Python) in Eclipse.

By the way, distinguish between the following two [key-bindings](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-keybindings.htm?cp=1_4_15):

- Click `F1`: Context-sensitive help for the active GUI-part (in your example: the Java editor itself)
- Click `F2`: Context-sensitive tooltip for the selected token (for example `String`,
  `toString`, `myVariable`)

You probably want `F2`.

Comment: Is `Show Tooltip Description` at all useful, though? This just shows the same popup box you get if you just hover the mouse over the name for a second or two.

Comment: Useful or not: That's the way it is implemented, consistently in all language editors of Eclipse.